# How can I achieve a drifting image mosaic background (URL Example given below)

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

http://horiyoshi-thethird.com/  (skip the intro)

I know very little about jQuery but I am used to setting javascript & css parameters etc if there is a plugin or something that simplifies things that someone could point me to

The drifting effect with multiple random images is the crucial part, the interactivity is not so important but a bonus.

Thanks so much,

Bryan

Comment: Good golly, that site is taking me whole minutes to load....

Comment: That site is flash based

Comment: I think he's just interested in mimicking the effect the effect.

Comment: I think that should also be possible with CSS3 and the canvas tag of HTML5...

Answer (score 0):

The background image isn't drifting; that's a separate layer of images, which drifts as a whole by computing a vector between the mouse cursor and the center of the window and slowly shifting the image layer in the opposite direction.

New images are added to the background just off-screen, before they drift into view. (You can see this by waiting until the page loads and starts drifting, then maximizing your browser window.)

As an aside, though, I can only imagine what awful things this is doing to the browser's memory footprint as time goes by.

If there's a plug-in to do this, though, I haven't heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears they are using a plugin called infinite drag. Though it doesn't quite have all the functionality, it should get you started.

http://ianli.com/infinitedrag/